# Android App, Firebase initialization successful but the website is still failing

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

In the firebase android app setup process there is a step to verify installation.

Currently when I run the app on my phone I get 
`I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful` 
in android studio but it is still failing the final step on the console.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: check internet connection on phone and computer

Comment: Thank you, its sometimes the little things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your Smartphone and Computer Should be Connected to the Internet.
& If you are in restricted a restricted area you should use VPN on both.